# How to match "as much as possible until the group is matched"?

Tags: regex, regex-group

Consider the string

```
hello world something 12345 somethingelse
```

I know that I will have `hello`, then some characters except numbers (I could list them if it helps), and then a set of digits. I would like to match this group of digits.

If I knew what is between `hello` and the digits, I would use `.*hello\sworld\s(\d*)\s` as the match string.

**Is there a way to say *"match the group of digits after `hello` (that `hello` is followed only by non-digits characters up until the sought group)"*?** (something between a greedy and a lazy match)

Comment: use: `hello\D+(\d+)`

Comment: @anubhava ah it is so simple! Thanks you very much. If you would not mind turning this into an answer I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
hello\D+(\d+)
```

Where:

- `\D+` matches 1+ non-digits after matching `hello`
- `(\d+)` matches 1+ digits and captures it in group #1